# Get wrong number of products on price sorting on product collection

Tags: magento-1.7, product-collection, sorting, category-products

I am trying to get product collection on listing page using this query. :

```
 $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId())
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSort($_GET['order'], $_GET['dir']);
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$_productCollection->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'visibility', 'neq'=>"1" )));
$_productCollection->addUrlRewrite(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId())->setPageSize(10)
    ->setCurPage(1);
 $_productCollection->getSelect();
```

This query works fine for `name` and `position` sorting but return 2 products on `price` sorting.What i am doing wrong ? without sort it work perfect.

Comment: please check  Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() give proper id it onlyb worki when it it category..

Comment: @AmitBera I know that its only return id on category page.what is the best solution for that replacement ? At the moment i am stuck on price sort.

Comment: add $_productCollection->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents() to $collection